# Export from MySQL with relations to JSON (for CouchDB) with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, couchdb, rdbms

I’m working on my master thesis where one of my goals is to run tests and experiments against the CouchDB database and tune the performance.

To do that I need some test data. I’ve created a piece of php code to generate some simple relational data for a MySQL database. The tables are:
*Customer

Product

Brand

Color

Checkout*

I’ve made some relations between for example Product and Colorid and Brandid and in the Checkout table I’ve a relation to Customerid and Productid.

I want to export this entirely data structure and the data with its relations to a JSON format for CouchDB. 
So I’ve a JSON string which should contain each customer with its attributes and its purchase with all the parameters for this product, and so on.

I’m thinking that it would look something like:

```
{
    "customer": {
        "customerid" : "1",
        "firstname" : "somefirstname",
        "lastname" : "somelastname",
        "email" : "my@mail.com",
        "country" : "USA",
        "datecreated" : "11111111111111"
    }
    "purchase" : {
        "purchaseid" : "1",
        "product": {
            "productname" : "mightymouse",
            "productcolor": "blue",
            "productbrand" : "Apple",
            "productprice" : "200",
            "checkoutdate" : "1111111111112"
        }
        "purchaseid" : "2",
        "product": {
            "productname" : "something nice",
            "productcolor": "yellow",
            "productbrand" : "Google",
            "productprice" : "5000",
            "checkoutdate" : "11111111113333"
        }
    }
}
```

It’s probably not the right data structure I’ve shown but it something like that.

Can this be done in PHP and if so, how do I create this kind of “CouchDB” ready JSON strings??

If I haven’t explained myself clearly, please let me know.

Thank you
Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has function json_encode, you can use it to convert any PHP object to its JSON representation (and json_decode to convert JSON string to object).
So:

- Use PHP database functions to read data from database.
- Create object of stdClass:

  $data = new stdClass;
- Fill this object with properties read from database like this:

  $customer = new stdClass;
  $customer->customerid = "1"
  ...
  $data->customer = $customer;
- Encode generated object with json_encode.